# What do I return from my Gulp task if I decide to do nothing?

Tags: coffeescript, stream, gulp

Suppose my gulp task decides to do nothing -- what should I return?

```
gulp.task 'maybe_transform_files', ->
    if check_something()
        gulp.src('src')
            .pipe transform_files()
            .pipe gulp.dest('target')
    else
        return something
```

In other situations, I might use the done() callback, but I don't think I can use it here, where I might return a stream.

Answer (score 6):

An old post, but no extra node package required now. `gulp.src('.')` should work just fine, as @Nick Perkins mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

have a look at [gulp-nop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nop)

what you can do to have no-op is

```
var nop = require('gulp-nop');

.....

return gulp.src('.').pipe(nop());
```

or if you are using [gulp-util](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util) you can use noop, similarly

Comment: How does that help?  How is that different from just returning "gulp.src('.')" ?

Comment: update: gulp-util is now deprecated according to [https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5](https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5),  so one should refrain from using it